# Uploading file for related entity

Tags: php, controller, symfony2

I see that my code smells.  The first file is a controller, and createAction.  But I don't know where to delegate this.

[BookController.php](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c2b29c105719fe8cfe17) - Whole controller class

So this is most 'smelly' code to me:

```
public function createAction(Request $request) {
    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

    $book = new Book();

    $form = $this->createForm(new BookType($user->getId()), $book);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid()) {
        $book->upload();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($book);
        $em->flush();

        $covers = $request->files->get('covers');
        foreach ($covers as $cover) {
            $coverObj = new BookCover();
            $coverObj->setFile($cover);
            $coverObj->setBook($book);
            $coverObj->upload();

            $em->persist($coverObj);
        }
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('matiit_book_homepage'));
    }

    return $this->render('MatiitBookBundle:Book:new.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]);
}
```

Rest of files:

- [new.html.twig](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/01836bc24113c3373e92)
- [Book.php](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7b52fe7f18459bb03a51)
- [BookType.php](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e2562cc03bc4b284acf6)
- [BookCover.php](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/72282c8467a9c1232d2f)

Uploading in entities is the second thing which bothers me.

It would be nice to know what is worth testing here - I have no experience with tests so it would be very useful for me.

Comment: How come you are not using a `postPersist` for the upload in your book, also why are you using `$coverObj->upload();` when it should already be covered by the `postPersist`? Also I don't think the first `$em->flush()` is needed. How come you have a field `file` in your form but are getting the files from an upload `covers`?

Answer (score 2):

### BookController.php

I don't see anything to change, the only thing which i could do different is the return line from

```
 return $this->render('MatiitBookBundle:Book:new.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]);
```

i would write something like this to make it more clear

```
return $this->render(
    'MatiitBookBundle:Book:new.html.twig', 
    [
        'form' => $form -> createView()
    ]
);
```

So if one day you need to add another line you will just add a `,` and the code will still look good.

### new.html.twig

Why `var $file`? Why this `$`? It remember me something which is related to `jQuery`... Do you really need this? I would just do `var file` or choose a more specific name. (no idea right now, `file` could be ok but what is `book_file`? a `input type="file"`?)

### Book.php

You use documentation only to specify the type of the fields? You could start with add the documentation of the fields and document all methods (or at least public/protected methods)

I'm wrong or here the indentation is a bit messed up? Could be just a copy/paste bug, anyway from `protected $category;` it wil look like you start write an inner class. (same for the end of the file)

Fix it if it's in your code.

What is `length`? I'm not English so maybe i'm wrong but i don't think `length` is a great name for a `Book` class (without documentation it's more hard to understand what is it).

It's the book pages? What about `totalPages`? It's the `length` (size) of the file in bytes? What about `fileSize`?

### BookType.php

```
class BookType extends AbstractType
```

Why not call your class `AbstractType` as `AbstractBookType`?

`AbstractType` could sound as something which is related to variables type, not your class.

I know you use `namespace`s but i think it's important to make the name of something very clear.

Here you could add documentation too.

### BookCover.php

It looks so similar to `Book.php`

Some methods are similar, maybe `Book` should have an instance of `BookCover` inside instead of recreate the methods from zero?

I need more info about it.

```
protected function getUploadRootDir()
{
   // the absolute directory path where uploaded
   // documents should be saved
   return __DIR__.'/../../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
}
```

I'm not a PHP expert, but what if one day you change the location? You should remember to edit this method inside `BookCover` and inside `Book` too! Can't you make it in a static field for the two classes?

And you should maintain the `/../../../../../` to point in the new location!

Anyway my review is more about style than other.

Comment: var named $file is because I like to name all cached jQuery variables with prefix $. It makes it easy to know that this is jQuery object with all its methods.

Comment: AbstractType is just a class from Symfony. Namespaces makes it self-explanatory - i can't agree.

Comment: To the rest I would agree. Thank You very much.

Comment: Suppose in another file (maybe the main file) you use it `AbstractType abc;` (example) what is `AbstractType`? One should go up and see the namespace?

Comment: it's the built in symfony class